# How to set text align and indentation in codemirror editor as it always start in the middle?

Tags: java, css, jsp, codemirror

I have problems using CodeMirror. When I typed my codes in the textarea, it will start in the middle and not at the most left even after going to next line.
Must I modify the CSS?

JSP:

```
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("myTextArea"), {
mode:"javascript",
lineNumbers: true,
autofocus: true
});
editor.setSize(500,680);
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvhVZ.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a CSS rule like `.CodeMirror { text-align: left!important; }` to override this.

Comment: It works for me now ,thanks! Are there any reasons why some configs or stylings do not work?

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing a similar issue then I found out that my `Parent Style-sheet` had an command `text-align: center`

I did not have `text-align: center` within my `Child style sheet`. So better check if there are any elements which have the styles `text-align: center` if so remove all then check.